# The artifacts when I click on button, which open the modal window in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a button, which open a modal window. When I click this button, field "Tasks" becomes in pixels. Can you help me to resolve this problem? This problem appears only in Google Chrome.

When I click on this button, modal window opens

[image]

Field "Tasks" becomes in pixels
[image]

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug (report to the Chrome team), graphics driver bug (update your graphics drivers and try whether software rendering resolves it), or GPU problem (it might be dying).